# Is it possible to process Azure Pipeline tasks console outputs?

Tags: logging, azure-pipelines, output

I'm trying to integrate Azure Pipelines into a release generation system but I'd like to "catch" all the console ouputs generated during the processing of the different tasks and process them (in real time, if possible) so that I can send them to our Observability system, pack them all and send them via email or, simply, analize them in order to find some determined data in there.

I've been looking for some "redirect output" option in the tasks, but found nothing about it.

The only option I found is that logs can be retrieved from the Azure REST API, but that needs to be performed after all the processing in the pipeline is finished.

Is this live logs retrieval possible to do? If so, how?

Would, for example, the use of output variables and a Powershell script included into the Pipeline itself do the job?

Would I necessarily need to perform a later call to the Azure DevOps API to retrieve all that info?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks so much!
Roberto Rodríguez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a steaming log API, since the agent logs can be viewed while the jobs are running, but that API isn't documented nor supported for this purpose. If you've ever looked at the live logs from the portal, you probably also know that if you open the logs while a job is in progress, you won't see any of the log messages that happened in the current task in progress, I wouldn't rely on these logs for any security or audit purposes for that reason.

Your best bet is to use the timeline API to list all of the steps in the job and the associated log files (steps can associate one or more log files). You can grab the logs for each step as soon as it's finished, even if the job itself is still in progress. [In this build task I fetch the logs of all tasks that have executed prior to the task itself](https://github.com/jessehouwing/azure-pipelines-tfvc-tasks/blob/main/tf-vc-fixparallel/v2/TfvcFixParallel.v3.ps1), that code could help you figure out how to fetch all the logs for the tasks that have executed up to the current point in time.

Alternatively, you might be able to grab the logs straight from the agent itself. All log files are streamed to disk on the agent live as things happen.

Comment: Thanks so much for your replay, @jessehouwing. I will take a look to the snippet an bear in mind the approach you suggested to define the log retrieval system. :-)